# How to edit writable locations in a document in Pages '09?

Tags: pages, text-editor, text

The following image shows a region of the sheet it is not possible to write or select. There the cursor is, if i write another letter it will show up on the next page.
[image]
How do i enable the document to let me write on that field? I have tried dragging the side markers, but they only control how far down the reference text is.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the page borders in the property sheet:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Inspector** (<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) → **Text inspector** → **More** and uncheck the **Keep lines together** box. The info on the following page will jump up into place.